# Draw 2 parallel lines between any 2 coordinates on the stage in AS3

Tags: coordinates, lines, parallels, actionscript-3

I am developping a web application, basically its a simple version of Illustrator/Flash. 
So soccer trainers can make schemes.
I made different tools like in Photoshop (line tool, rectangle tool, ..).
All of these work.

However now i need to develop a tool where the **user can draw a double parallel line**. I would like to be able to define the **distance between those 2 lines in a variable**.
I need to draw 2 parallel lines between any 2 points on the stage. Like the line tool in Photoshop/Illustrator , but it draws 2 lines at once.

---

It should basically work like this

**1) on mouse down:**

create a new graphics object and register the X and Y where the user clicked. start to listen for Mouse Move.



**2) on mouse move:**


clear the graphics object, draw the double line from the original mouse position to the current mouse position. redraw on every mouse move.



**3) on mouse up:**


 
stop listening for events and add the double line to the stage.

---

This worked perfectly for drawing a single line, but I'm having troubles with 2 parallel lines. They don't stay parallel to each other or the rotation doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to plot the points this way:

```
90 degrees (UP from the START point)        90 degrees (UP from the END point)
|                                                                            |
START- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - END
|                                                                            |
90 degrees (DOWN from the START point)    90 degrees (DOWN from the END point)
```

Once you determine those 6 points (2 for the top-line, 2 for the mouse start and end, and 2 for the bottom-line), you can join the pair of points for the top-line and bottom-line together with a lineTo(...) command to give you this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

START                                                                      END

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To know what is the current angle formed by your START and END point, you need the deltas (difference between two values) of your point's X and Y values.

So **X2 - X1 = DeltaX**, and **Y2 - Y1 = DeltaY**.

Then, put those deltas in `Math.atan2(y:Number, x:Number):Number`. The returned value is in radians I believe, so to work with degrees, you can do the conversion by multiplying the result with **180 / Math.PI**.

This won't be really necessary however, as we can resume the rest of the calculations in radians. It would be useful to store the above value (180/Math.PI) in a variable.

If we continue with Radians, it is important to convert our 90 degrees to Radians.

- **90 / radians** gives us a number to offset from our START and END point to solve the **top line**.
- **-90 / radians** gives us the  number to offset from our START and END point to solve the **bottom line**.

in other words...

This is a whole solution that I quickly tested, I apologize if it doesn't work 100%:

```
var startPoint:Point = new Point(10, 0); //Replace by start-mouse location
var endPoint:Point = new Point(20, 0); //Replace by end-mouse location

var mouseAngle:Number = Math.atan2( endPoint.y - startPoint.y, endPoint.x - startPoint.x );

var angle:Number;
var lineHalfGap:Number = 100 * .5; //Replace 100 by your seperation value
var radians:Number = 180 / Math.PI;
angle = 90 / radians + mouseAngle;
var topOffsetX:Number = Math.cos( angle ) * lineHalfGap;
var topOffsetY:Number = Math.sin( angle ) * lineHalfGap;
angle = -90 / radians + mouseAngle;
var bottomOffsetX:Number = Math.cos( angle ) * lineHalfGap;
var bottomOffsetY:Number = Math.sin( angle ) * lineHalfGap;

var topStart:Point = new Point(startPoint.x + topOffsetX, startPoint.y + topOffsetY);
var topEnd:Point = new Point(endPoint.x + topOffsetX, endPoint.y + topOffsetY);

var bottomStart:Point = new Point(startPoint.x + bottomOffsetX, startPoint.y + bottomOffsetY);
var bottomEnd:Point = new Point(endPoint.x + bottomOffsetX, endPoint.y + bottomOffsetY);

trace(topStart, topEnd, bottomStart, bottomEnd);
```

Obviously there's a few variables you will have to replace / substitute for your own (like the mouse locations and the separation value for your line gap), but this should do the trick.

A running example can be found here:

http://pierrechamberlain.ca/blog/2012/08/math-101-parallel-lines-two-points/

Comment: hmm it's a little off... I tried it with a mouse-move example and the 90 degrees up and down is always  directly above and under the start and end point. I'll try to tweak this so it is 90 degrees around the angle formed by the two initial points.

Comment: There, fixed it! works like a charm in the example I've put together locally. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are my hero!
I am still a student and this was for a holiday job. I am not super good at math (yet). And this worked like a charm!.