# How to evenly adjust some area to polygon (extend a polygon)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to add 1 km to every terminal point of a polygon. Please see the picture of what I exactly mean:
[image]

1) The inner polygon is the initial polygon I have (the one with red dots inside and a green line as a border).

2) The outer line (a blue one) is the polygon I want to get by adding 1 km (or some other distance) to every terminal point of the initial polygon.

How may I achieve it? Does Google Maps API provide some special functions? I'm not asking for ready solution, please give me an advice or links where I could find an additional info.

**UPD 1:**

@geocodezip, sometimes `chainHull_2D` makes wrong calculations and draws a line inside of a polygon. Please, see the picture. When I set 'polygon.setEditable(true)' that line is also editable and makes a hole in a polygon.

[image]

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_ConvexHull_extend.asp)? (simplistic algorithm)

Comment: Any idea how to get similar function in PHP in order to search for records from MySQL within an extended polygon (using ST_CONTAINS)?

Comment: Is it a library which draws the outer ploygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The atan of the delta of point 1 and point 2 gives you the angle in radians. You can add 90/radians to get the offset. The cosinus of the new angle multiply with the gap gives the x coordinate. The sinus gives you the y coordinate: [Draw 2 parallel lines between any 2 coordinates on the stage in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796230/draw-2-parallel-lines-between-any-2-coordinates-on-the-stage-in-as3).