# Is there a way to use Google Maps API v3 on a server side (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I extend a polygon shape on the client. Please see my question ([How to evenly adjust some area to polygon (extend a polygon)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017599/how-to-evenly-adjust-some-area-to-polygon-extend-a-polygon)) to understand what I exactly mean. I do all the calculations in browser and then send a result to server and store it in DB. I use this function (from [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_ConvexHull_extend.asp)):

```
    this.extendPolygon = function(polyline, offset) {
        var distance = Number(offset) * 1000;
        var numPts = polyline.getPath().getLength();
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        for (var i=0; i< numPts; i++) {
            bounds.extend(polyline.getPath().getAt(i));
        }

        var center = bounds.getCenter();
        var extendedPolyPts = [];
        for (var i=0; i< numPts; i++) {
            var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(center,polyline.getPath().getAt(i));
            var initialDist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center,polyline.getPath().getAt(i));
            var extendedDist = initialDist + distance;
            var extendedPt = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(center, extendedDist, heading);
            extendedPolyPts.push(extendedPt);
        }
        extendedPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
            // map: map,
            paths:extendedPolyPts, 
            fillColor:"#00FF00",
            strokeWidth:2, 
            fillOpacity:0.4, 
            strokeColor:"#0000FF",
            strokeOpacity:0.5
        });

        return extendedPoly;
    };
```

But I'd like to do calculations on a server side. Is it possible to run the function on a server? It uses these functions of GM API:

```
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading
google.maps.LatLngBounds
polyline.getPath().getLength()
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset
google.maps.Polygon
```

Comment: [This any help](https://github.com/moshen/node-googlemaps)?

Comment: Do you want to just echo a static image of the map or do you want it to be responsive but just do the calculation on the server. If what you want is the latter what you need is ajax. Just make a rest api that takes the parameters you want, calculates what you want and sends the response to the client.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? the only way I found around this was to mimic the Google functions in a self written API together with what https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib provides.